# jQuery / CSS: How to add page breaks dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, page-break

I have an HTML page that contains a form large table where a user can delete, move and add rows dynamically.

When printing the form there should not be more than 25 rows on a page to prevent the font size from getting too small and to avoid other layout issues. 
I was therefore looking for something to add a page break dynamically after every 25 rows.

The only thing I came across on the **CSS side** is the `page-break-after` style which could then perhaps be used with dynamically added divs (like `<div class="page-break"></div>`) but I am not sure about the right approach here.

On the **jQuery side** the following should give me the current number of rows in my table:

```
$(this).closest('table').find('tbody > tr').length
```

**Also,** I wouldn't actually need to create a real new page but just want to re-add the table's head so that every printed page starts with the same thead and then contains a maximum of 25 rows.

Can someone help me with sharing a link or example for something like this or can you let me know if this is not possible at all ?

Many thanks in advance, 
Mike

Comment: Printing is tough because you don't know the settings of the user's printer.  A user might be printing in landscape mode instead of portrait, or using legal-sized paper instead of letter, so setting it to a certain number of rows tends to cause problems.

Comment: @andi: Thanks - this is something I would be able to cover here with general instructions etc. so in this specific case I would not have to worry about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using the THEAD and TFOOT tag?
That's exactly what these tags are for :)

[Documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#edef-THEAD):

> Table rows may be grouped into a head, foot, and body sections, (via the THEAD, TFOOT and TBODY elements, respectively). Row groups convey additional structural information and may be rendered by user agents in ways that emphasize this structure. User agents may exploit the head/body/foot division to support scrolling of body sections independently of the head and foot sections. **When long tables are printed, the head and foot information may be repeated on each page that contains table data.**

Comment: Thanks, Nic ! Yes, I do and in addition they also have a class thead resp. tfoot but I don't know how to apply this here for the following pages as I am pretty new to jQuery.

Comment: Just to add here, the thead and tfoot work fine on my first page but I dont know how to get them on every following page in CSS + how to set up the table so that it breaks after every 25 rows in jQuery.

Comment: Hey @keewee279. You original messages says:
"When printing the form there should not be more than 25 rows on a page to prevent the font size from getting too small and to avoid other layout issues."

Now that I'm reading that again, by "printing" you probably don't mean an actual print of the page. Am I right?

Comment: Thanks for the update to your answer. So do I understand it right that just having the thead and tfooter covers the repeating of them and I dont need to set specific page breaks in CSS then ?

Comment: Yes, I mean an actual print of the page resp. of the form on it as this is meant to be signed and submitted physically afterwards.

Comment: In that case using thead and tfoot should be enough to repeat the header/footer if your table doesn't fit in one page

Comment: wow, thanks - I didn't know about how these print on every page automatically.  But I just tried it and it worked.  Cool!

Comment: Thanks for this - and for adding the documentation above ! I decided to accept this answer since the documentation is the main part here but will combine it with the additional styles that mattytommo provided. Both answers together are perfect for me. :)

Answer (score 3):

Some browsers allow this by default using the `thead` tag, but if you want a solution for all browsers, then you can enforce the style:

```
thead {
    display: table-header-group;
}
```

Obviously you need to be using a `thead` to go with that though.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have a thead and tfooter. Does table-header-group set this to be repeated on every page ?

Comment: @keewee279 It basically tells the browser that the `thead` should behave like a table header group, thus render on every page when printing.

Comment: Thanks - this is very helpful ! Would I need something similar for the tfoot as well ?

Comment: @keewee279 No problems, you want the footer to be displayed on every page as well?

Comment: Yes and ideally it should work in different (newer) browsers, not caring about Opera or Netscape.

Comment: @keewee279 No problems, then you need `tfoot { display: table-footer-group; }` as well.

Comment: Thanks again ! Is this supported cross-browser and also in older IE versions (up to IE 8 ) ?

Comment: @keewee279 I think it goes way back, possibly works in IE 5.5 just in case you have any prehistorical creatures visiting your site :)

Comment: Awesome - thanks ! That should work and I think I don't have to worry about the 25 row limit anymore then. :)

Comment: I decided to accept Nic's answer since he was a bit faster and the documentation there is the main part here but will combine it with the additional styles you provided. Both answers together are perfect for me. :) Hope it's ok this way.

Comment: @keewee279 Sure no problems, glad you got there in the end :)